# How to update status bar programatically?

Tags: java, android

I have just made the application which reads unread sms from my device and set "read" status as "the message has been read". It works without problem, but I have a one little problem - I update status of a message programatically using my application, but the sms icon is still being seen on the status bar. How can I fix it programatically?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fix it"?

Comment: I want that status bar will be clear when I set "read" flag as "1"

Comment: You mean you need to remove the notification of the new message all together?

Answer (score 0):

Removing Notifications created by other apps, is not possible. You can't do it. And thats bad as well.